# docker compose with swarm and spring boot, cannot connect to database on different node

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: pedramrn/webapp:0.1.4
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - main
    working_dir: /src
    restart: never
    depends_on:
      - db-postgresql
    links:
      - db-postgresql

  lb:
    image: dockercloud/haproxy:1.5
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - main
    environment:
      - ADDITIONAL_SERVICES=springbootdockertemplate:app


  db-postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.5
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - data-postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - main
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres


volumes:
  data-postgresql:

networks:
  main:
```

This is the datasource `url: jdbc:postgresql://db-postgresql:5432/postgres`

If I remove the `links: db-postgresql` spring boot cannot connect to postgres database, though it will works without `links` on a single node but not with each container on a different node.

on the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/), with the new multi-host networking feature, containers can resolves with their names.

*Note:* I have set up the keystore with consul according to documentation.

```
Client:                                       
 Version:      1.11.1                         
 API version:  1.23                           
 Go version:   go1.5.4                        
 Git commit:   5604cbe                        
 Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:44:17 2016       
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64                  

Server:                                       
 Version:      swarm/1.2.3                    
 API version:  1.22                           
 Go version:   go1.5.4                        
 Git commit:   eaa53c7                        
 Built:        Fri May 27 17:25:03 UTC 2016   
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64   

Dev system: Windows 8.1 X64
```

Comment: What is the version of docker you have installed?

Comment: @Shibashis I have installed the most recent version of Toolbox. Also I updated the question.

Comment: i tested a similar config with a custom network and i could ping other containers .. have u tried pinging the dbcontainer from inside the app container

Comment: @Shibashis Yes I've tried, When all the containers are in same node they can see each others and ping them, but when they are on different nodes they cannot. From 51dfd31ab247 (10.0.0.3) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable. Can it be the keystore or consul discovery fault?

Comment: @Shibashis You can see the demo in docker blog https://blog.docker.com/2015/11/docker-multi-host-networking-ga/